# Message sharing using 'feed' method in Facebook not appearing in news feed

Tags: facebook

I tried the below code to share a link on the Facebook from my site, but it appears only in wall, i want to appear the shared thing in both wall and news feed of Facebook, any method for that?

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    link: 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to     interface with users.'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Exactly the question I want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `method` to `'share'`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Yes it does. If he changes 'feed' to 'share' it fixes his issue.

Comment: I still feel this is better off as a comment.

Comment: And how will he mark this as the answer when it works?